# NHibernate Current Session Context Problem

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-3

I've recently moved from using an ISession directly to a wrapped ISession, Unit-of-Work type pattern.

I used to test this using SQL Lite (in-memory). I've got a simple helper class that configures my SessionFactory, created an ISession and then built the schema using SchemaExport and then returned my ISession and the schema lived until I closed the session. I've changed this slightly so that I now configure a SessionFactory, create an ISession, build the schema, and pass the factory to my NHibernateUnitOfWork and return that to my test.

```
var databaseConfiguration =
                SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory()
                .Raw("connection.release_mode", "on_close")
                .Raw("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");

            var config = Fluently.Configure().Database(databaseConfiguration).Mappings(
                m =>
                {
                    foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
                    {
                        m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(assembly);
                        m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssembly(assembly);
                    }
                });

            Configuration localConfig = null;
            config.ExposeConfiguration(x =>
                {
                    x.SetProperty("current_session_context_class", "thread_static"); // typeof(UnitTestCurrentSessionContext).FullName);
                    localConfig = x;
                });

            var factory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
            ISession session = null;

            if (openSessionFunction != null)
            {
                session = openSessionFunction(factory);
            }

            new SchemaExport(localConfig).Execute(false, true, false, session.Connection, null);

            UnitTestCurrentSessionContext.SetSession(session);

            var unitOfWork = new NHibernateUnitOfWork(factory, new NHibernateUTCDateTimeInterceptor());
            return unitOfWork;
```

Internally, NHibernateUnitOfWork needs to get the ISession which was used to create the schema or the in-memory database won't actually have a schema, so this is the method it calls to get the ISession.

```
private ISession GetCurrentOrNewSession()
        {
            if (this.currentSession != null)
            {
                return this.currentSession;
            }

            lock (this)
            {
                if (this.currentSession == null)
                {
                    // get an existing session if there is one, otherwise create one
                    ISession session;
                    try
                    {
                        session = this.sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.Write(ex.Message);
                        session = this.sessionFactory.OpenSession(this.dateTimeInterceptor);
                    }

                    this.currentSession = session;
                    this.currentSession.FlushMode = FlushMode.Never;
                }
            }
```

The problem is that `this.sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession` always throws an exception saying that the `ICurrentSessionContext` isn't registered.

I've tried loads of different ways to set the property and different values (as you can see above, "thread_static" and my own `ICurrentSessionContext`) but none seem to work.

Anyone got any advice

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
try
{
    if (NHibernate.Context.CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(sessionFactory))
    {
        session = sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
    }
    else
    {
        session = sessionFactory.OpenSession(this.dateTimeInterceptor);
        NHibernate.Context.CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.Write(ex.Message);
    throw;
}
```

Comment: This seems to have worked, I'll confirm properly later today and accept. Thanks

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis at the end of the 'if' statement.